# How to prevent showing a dialog when android app is in background

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I start to download/upload a file in a background thread and end up showing up a dialog when the operation fails.

For cases when download/upload is in progress, app can be taken to background and network might get turned off or might face temporary disconnection. I will get the following crash if I try to show the dialog when the app is in background.

```
W/System.err(10235): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
E/ConnectivityService( 455): EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED from unknown NetworkAgent
D/ConnectivityService( 455): setProvNotificationVisibleIntent: E visible=false networkType=0 extraInfo=null
W/System.err(10235): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
W/System.err(10235): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
W/System.err(10235): at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
W/System.err(10235): at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
W/System.err(10235): at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
W/System.err(10235): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
W/System.err(10235): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
W/System.err(10235): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask)
```

I would certainly want to avoid this situation to show the dialog while the app is in background. The dialog should show when the app resumes. How can I do that gracefully without any need to set boolean flags.

**I don't want to check whether the app is currently in background or not. I only intend to show the dialog automatically when app comes to background again.**

Answer (score 0):

......
Previous code to check apps in background(Has been Deleted).....

This method will return true if app is in background. You can use this condition to show dialog

```
if(!isAppIsInBackground(context)){
  //show the dialog
}else{
  //Do as you need 
}
```

### Edit

You can show dialog like this using a activity as a dialog

### 1. Create An Activity

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

String message = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);


    message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    if(message!=null) {
        displayAlert(message);
    }
}


 private void displayAlert(String msg)
 {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Network alert!");
    builder.setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
 }
}
```

### 2. Edit Activity Theme from Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

### 3. Write this to show dialog

```
private void showDialog(String your_message){
   Intent intent=new Intent(this,DialogActivity.class);   
   intent.putExtra("message",message);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

This Way Dialog will show automatically.
It will prevent showing dialog if app on background.
If app is not on background on any activity it can show the dialog.

### I do it and tested it 100% works...

Comment: You can replace your custom dialog inside displayAlert() method.